# Is there a way to access the unmatched value in a switch statement?

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I want to access the value used in the switch statement in the default clause without first creating a temporary local var for the value, for example:

```
switch i + 5 {
    case 2: // ...
    case 7: // ...
    default:
      print("\(switchValue)") 
}
```

Is there such a thing as, for example, a `newValue` in the `didSet` property clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can conditionally bind to a variable, with no condition (so it acts like `case _` or `default`

```
let i = 123

switch i + 5 {
    case 2: break // ...
    case 7: break // ...
    case let switchValue:
        print("\(switchValue)") 
}
```

To be fair, you probably shouldn't do this.

Comment: This works but why do you say this probably shouldn't be done?

Comment: @andrewz `i + 5` probably has some meaning in your business domain. You should label that with a good variable name. Otherwise you end up with [`i  = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );               // what the fuck?`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root)

Comment: Oh you're commenting on the switch value expression, I thought you were commenting on your proposed solution, ie `case let switchValue:`

Comment: Well if the switched expression is already named variable, then you can just reuse it, rather than needing to bond a new variable like this

Comment: My original problem involved a call to a function, ie. switch myFunction() { ... } instead of i + 5 .. I guess if I used that we wouldn't be having a discussion about coding style.  Thanks for your great help.

Comment: Ah, well that could actually be okay, so long as the function is named well, it'll have the same documenting purpose as an intermediate variable would. Of course, if the `switch myFunctionWithALongName()` line gets too long, you should extract it too.